# Array out of bounds exception in neural network code

Tags: c#, arrays, iteration, neural-network

I know that there are already a large number of these questions asked but my problem is code specific.
For this reason, I don't know how to make it relevant to a large number of people.

I am practicing the iteration in preparation for creating my first neural network (trying to understand a possible structure I could write it).
The program aims to go through and assign weights in a similar way a neural network might. This does not use the math, it is for iteration purposes only. So if there is any possible suggestions/ recommendations how would be best to write it I would be grateful.

Main question:

The first out of bounds I can see. However, the one towards the bottom I cannot see or understand where I have gone wrong.

```
using System;

namespace Layers
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Random Rand = new Random();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // NOTE: The first hidden layer (0) will be the input layer.
            // Initialize Layers.
            Console.WriteLine("How many layers?");
            int[][] HiddenLayers = new int[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())][];

            for (int HLCount = 0; HLCount < HiddenLayers.Length; HLCount++)
            {
                // Make the first layer the input.
                if (HLCount == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("How many inputs?");
                } else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("How many cells in Hidden Layer " + HLCount + "?");
                }
                HiddenLayers[HLCount] = new int[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
            }

            // Set the values for the inputs.
            for (int InputCount = 0; InputCount < HiddenLayers[0].Length; InputCount++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the value for input " + (InputCount + 1) + ":");
                HiddenLayers[0][InputCount] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            // Initialize the weights.
            int[][] Weights = new int[HiddenLayers.Length][]; // Set of weights for each layer.

            for (int WeightCount = 0; WeightCount < Weights.Length; WeightCount++)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Create weights for the layers underneath. +1 attaches it to the layer below but would exceed the array.
                    Weights[WeightCount] = new int[HiddenLayers[WeightCount +1].Length]; 
                } catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

            for (int inputCount = 0; inputCount < Weights[0].Length; inputCount++)
            {
                Weights[0][inputCount] = Rand.Next(10); // Set first layers weights.
            }

            int intCount = 0;
            for (int LayerIndex = 1; LayerIndex < HiddenLayers.Length; LayerIndex++)
            {
                // Re-calculate weights. Go through layer and change weights.
                if (intCount < Weights[LayerIndex-1].Length)
                {
                    Weights[LayerIndex][intCount] = Rand.Next(1, 10);
                    intCount++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Layer: " + Convert.ToString(LayerIndex));

                // Go through the cells on the Layer.
                for (int CellIndex = 0; CellIndex < HiddenLayers[LayerIndex].Length; CellIndex++)
                {
                    // Out of bounds exception. Catching it affects the overall performance of the outcome.
                    HiddenLayers[LayerIndex][CellIndex] += (Convert.ToInt32(HiddenLayers[LayerIndex - 1][CellIndex]) + Convert.ToInt32(Weights[LayerIndex][CellIndex]));
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void getWeights()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is some more information as to what I am trying to make. With some modifications such as the user being able to determine the layer sizes, inputs etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9cN3.png

The inputs I used was:
3 layers
3 inputs
hidden layer 1: 3
hidden layer 2: 3
input 1: 12
input 2: 13

Comment: Run it is the debugger and inspect your variables.

Comment: HiddenLayers[LayerIndex][CellIndex] before the += is 0.
LayerIndex is 1 and CellIndex is 2.
Weights[LayerIndex][CellIndex] is 0.
The HiddenLayers[LayerIndex][CellIndex]  after the += just says public int System.Array.this[int index]

Answer (score 1):

**MOST IMPORTANT:** do not *ever* use `try`/`catch` to "solve" an `IndexOutOfRangeException` problem. For that matter, don't use it to solve *any* exception that you did not expect to get. Doing so is guaranteed to be the wrong thing to do, always. If an exception occurs that you did not anticipate could occur, then you have a bug and you need to fix the bug, not try to sweep it under the rug with `try`/`catch`.

As far as the rest of the question goes…

When I run your code, I get a `NullReferenceException` due to an uninitialized array member (because you caught the earlier exception instead of fixing your code). This happens before the code reaches the line where you claim `IndexOutOfRangeException` occurs.

Just looking at the program statement you are asking about, I see no reason that should throw an exception. But it's hard to say for sure, because the code isn't written in a way that could reproduce the problem you're describing.

Note that because you force us to enter data to run the program, we have no way to know if we are running with the same data you are. Thus, you have not provided [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

When I change the code so that the first computational loop looks like this:

```
for (int WeightCount = 0; WeightCount < Weights.Length; WeightCount++)
{
    // Create weights for the layers underneath (caught out of bounds exception which doesn't seem to matter).
    Weights[WeightCount] = new int[HiddenLayers[WeightCount].Length];
}
```

…both exceptions I was able to reproduce go away and the code runs to completion. Whether this is really what you want, I have no idea. It seems like a reasonable thing to do, but without more detail about the actual algorithm you're trying to implement, it's impossible to know for sure.

If the above does not seem to address your question in a useful way, please improve the question so that a) you include a good code example, and b) it's clear what you are asking.

Comment: First paragraph is the most valuable lesson OP can learn today.

Comment: Thanks. Initially the Try/Catch was used as a debugging technique but I decided to leave it in because I thought it would get to the problem without me having to re-modify the code back to how it was before I made several changes (my mistake and thanks for pointing out the error caused).

The +1 was added because I needed the weights to be determined for all of the layers below the input layer. Without it I thought it would give weights to the input layer too. (See image URL in edit).

Comment: _"+1 was added because I needed the weights to be determined for all of the layers below the input layer"_ -- if you're going to do that, you need to decide what action to take for a layer for which there is no input layer above (i.e. the index+1 is out of range of the length of the input layer array).